# Add View in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Just wondering where they may have moved the tooling to right click on an action method and add a view. I get no menu option.

Comment: I too am curious as to where this has gone as well as a whole host of other context menu dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Right now (ASP.Net 5/Core 1.0 RC1), that tooling does not exist.

There are plenty of places where the tooling is not there yet. For example, in the 'Web API' project template you cannot use scaffolding or add authentication during project creation via Visual Studio.

The 'web application' project template is the most complete but still has holes.

What I normally do is just copy one of the other views (About.cshtml for example) and edit the places I need to edit, you'll get to the same result.

Thanks